# Stop CakePHP Htmlhelper image method from replacing special charcters with HTML entities when trying to display image in browser

Tags: php, html, image, cakephp, character-encoding

I want to Stop CakePHP Htmlhelper image method from replacing special charcters with HTML entities when trying to display image in browser

My code are as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image($issue['Issue']['issue_cover']); ?>
```

This is what I expect in the imge src attribute if I shoud inspect element:

```
src="/cakemagapp/img/uploads/file name(1).png"
```

But I keep getting this:

```
src="/cakemagapp/img/uploads%5Cfile%20name%20%281%29.png"
```

however when I echoed the path all works well like so:

```
<?php echo "/cakemagapp/img/". $issue['Issue']['issue_cover']; ?>
```

Output: `/cakemagapp/img/uploads/file name(1).png`

Obviously, chakephp is replacing whitespace-" ",prenthesis-"()" and forwardslash-"/" with encoded characters
Somebody please suggest a way to resolve this.

Comment: Why? Those characters are supposed to be encoded in url.

Comment: On a side note, `%5C` is the URL encoded represenation of ``\`` (backward slash), I'm pretty that CakePHP does _not_ URL encode forward slashes.

Comment: Thnks ndm, it could the encoding is done twice, I guess it could be a configuration on my localhost(Xampp). I have trid a number of options non worked. However when i echo the src attribute of the image without using cakePHP Htmlhelper image method  images are display as expected. However I will still like to know why the baskslaches are renderd as %5C .Thanks